# Unity c# Firing another GameObject's methods. Better way?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, invoke

I have TCP client (Unity c#) and server (WinForms app c#). I need my server sending some JSON commands, like this:

```
{ ""ObjName"": ""Cube_2"", ""Method"":""MoveLeft"", ""Delay"":0}
```

This certain command says to find GameObject "Cube_2" and fire method "MoveLeft".

When i recieve this from server, i convert it into my AOSCommand class:

```
public class AOSCommand
{
    public string ObjName;
    public string Method;
    public int delay;
}
```

And then i do the following (which i think is not the best solution, so here is a question):

```
private void ProcessCommand(AOSCommand command)
    {
        GameObject cube = GameObject.Find(command.ObjName);
        MonoBehaviour script = cube.GetComponent(command.ObjName.Split(new string[] {"_"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]) as MonoBehaviour;
        script.Invoke(command.Method, command.delay);
    }
```

***How can i fire some method from AOSCommand.Method string in a better way?***

The script attached to Cube_2 (and Cube_1 and may be attached to unknown count of other objects):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject thisObj;

    private void Start()
    {
        thisObj = this.gameObject;
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        thisObj.transform.Translate(new Vector3(1,0,0));
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        thisObj.transform.Translate(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you consider wrong.

You should have a single script that takes care of the parsing of the incoming data, this would remove the need to search for a component, it would always be the same.

Then you can have a dictionary of  to replace the invoke call.

So your snippet turns into:

```
private void ProcessCommand(AOSCommand command)
{
    GameObject cube = GameObject.Find(command.ObjName);
    AOSDispatch dispatch = cube.GetComponent<AOSDispatch>()
    if(dispatch == null){ return; } // or debug or exception
    dispatch.Call(command);
}
```

this is on the main receiver. Then comes the script on the cubes:

```
public class AOSDispatch : MonoBehaviour
{
    Dictionary<string, Action> dict;
    void Start()
    {
        dict.Add("MoveLeft", MoveLeft);
        dict.Add("MoveRight", MoveRight);
    }
    public void Call(AOSCommand command)
    {
        if(dict.Contains(command.Method) == false){  return; } //Or debug
        // use the delay as well as you wish
        dict[command.Method]();
    }
    private void MoveLeft(){}  
    private void MoveRight(){}
}
```

This is not necessarily better, just my two cents on it.

EDIT: there was comment mentioning the json could contain the script type to know what script to use. I would not go this way. AOSDispatch will take care of the dispatching of the message.

Message says MoveLeft, AOSDispatch can either treat the info or forward to a movement controller:

```
public class AOSDispatch : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MoveController moveCtrl = null;
    Dictionary<string, Action> dict;
    void Start()
    {
        dict.Add("MoveLeft", this.moveCtrl.MoveLeft);
        dict.Add("MoveRight", this.moveCtrl.MoveRight);
    }
    public void Call(AOSCommand command)
    {
        if(dict.Contains(command.Method) == false){  return; } //Or debug
        // use the delay as well as you wish
        dict[command.Method]();
    }
}
public class MoveController: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void MoveLeft(){}  
    private void MoveRight(){}
}
```

there you go, message is forward and cleanly, the AOSDispatch does only the job it is meant to do, dispatch the AOS.

SECONDARY EDIT:

On second thought, here is an improved version.
Create a DispatchManager game object and add the following script:

```
public class AOSDispatch:MonoBehaviour
{
     private IDictionary<string, AOSController> dict;
     void Awake(){
           this.dict = new Dictionary<string, AOSController>(); 
           AOSController.RaiseCreation += ProcessCreation;
           AOSController.RaiseDestruction += ProcessDestruction;
     }
    void OnDestroy()
    {
           AOSController.RaiseCreation -= ProcessCreation;
           AOSController.RaiseDestruction -= ProcessDestruction;
    }
    private void ProcessCreation(AOSController controller){
         this.dict.Add(controller.name, controller);
    }
    private void ProcessDestruction(AOSController controller){
         AOSController temp= null;
         if(this.dict.TryGetValue(controller.name, out temp) == true){
             this.dict.Remove(name);
        }
    }
    private void ProcessCommand(AOSCommand command)
    {
        AOSController controller = null;
        if(this.dict.TryGetValue(command.ObjName, out controller) == true){
             controller.Call(command);
             return;
        }
    }
}
```

and then on the objects you have the AOSController that forwards the info as before (just renaming):

```
public class AOSController: MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action<AOSController> RaiseCreation;
    public static event Action<AOSController> RaiseDestruction;
    [SerializeField] private MoveController moveCtrl = null;
    Dictionary<string, Action> dict;
    void Start()
    {
        if(RaiseCreation != null) { RaiseCreation(this); }
        dict.Add("MoveLeft", this.moveCtrl.MoveLeft);
        dict.Add("MoveRight", this.moveCtrl.MoveRight);
    }
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if(RaiseDestruction != null) { RaiseDestruction(this); }
    }
    public void Call(AOSCommand command)
    {
        if(dict.Contains(command.Method) == false){  return; } //Or debug
        // use the delay as well as you wish
        dict[command.Method]();
    }
}
public class MoveController: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void MoveLeft(){}  
    private void MoveRight(){}
}
```

On Awake, the Dispatch registers to the static event from the AOSController. In the AOSController.Start, the object triggers the event and passes itself to the AOSDispatch. That one adds it to the dictionary. On destruction, the AOSDispatch gets the event and removes the AOSController.

Now you have a collection that at any given time contains all the AOSController in the scene.

As a result, you don't need to perform a GameObject.Find since you can get the object from the dictionary (real fast process).

Comment: Many thanks! I do think your way should be a little faster.

Comment: I'd also add a type to your Json command in order to use `FindObjectOfType<T>` that's more typesafe.

Comment: You don't need the type if you rely on the AOSDispatch to know what to do.

Comment: @ИванДобряков I have added a secondary edit which uses events. If there is something you do not understand, please ask.